# What is the use of "vite fait"?

Tags: expressions

I heard lot of people use this expression. Can you guys give me some examples and the cases in which we use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« Vite fait » signifie « réalisé rapidement » mais pas forcement rigoureusement.

*a contrario*, on peut trouver ce groupe de mots dans l'expression « Vite fait, bien fait » qui signifie « réalisé rapidement et rigoureusement ».

Comment: Merci pour le retour rapide! Alors par exemple si je veux demander un service de mon ami qui est un peu occupé, si je peux dire ca: "Mais vas-y! Ca prend pas du temps, ce sera vite fait!"?

Comment: Oui, c'est une bonne utilisation.

Comment: Et aussi « vite fait, mal fait », qui reste une blague, mais ça permet d'enlever tout doute s'il en restait.

Comment: Je l'ai bien compris, merci à vous tous :)

Answer (score 4):

Le sens principal de l'expression a été bien expliqué dans les autres réponses.

Je voulais ajouter qu'il existe un autre usage de l'expression, assez récent, qui a déformé le sens initial de l'expression pour signifier *à la rigueur*, même dans des contextes où la contrainte n'a strictement rien de temporel.

Un exemple entendu tout récemment :

> Alors ça t'a plu le concert hier soir ?
>
> Mouais... vite fait.

(le contexte établissant clairement que la réponse ne signifiait pas que les musiciens ont expédié les morceaux comme pour s'en débarasser... c'était réellement une manière de dire un *oui* très atténué.)

Comment: +1 Je pense que ce sens est très employé et qu'il faut le souligner. Par contre je pense qu'il est important de préciser que **le registre est familier** ici, attention. Dans l'exemple donné ici, on peut aussi rapprocher le sens de *vite fait* avec *bof* ou *moyen*.

Comment: @Joffrey: +1 pour ton commentaire. Le sens de cette expression m'est plus clair quand hier un de mes amis l'a utilisée. On était en train de se discuter sur l'anglais et il disait qu'il comprend **vite fait** l'anglais. Ca veut dire **moyen**.

Comment: @NhonNguyen Tout à fait, toujours dans le registre familier, ton ami aurait pu dire "Je comprends *moyen* l'anglais". Il s'agit d'un français courant, mais grammaticalement incorrect. La phrase correcte équivalente utiliserait l'adverbe *"moyennement"* au lieu de l'adjectif *"moyen"*.

Answer (score 2):

*Vite fait* peut aussi très familièrement s'utiliser comme locution adverbiale, synonyme de *rapidement* : « J'écris ce message vite fait. »